# CLLocationManagerの使い方について

Tags: swift, delegate

CLLocationManagerを使って、delegateを使って通知を受ける際に、なぜプロパティとして、
CLLocationManager型のプロパティを持たなければいけないのでしょうか？

```
class LocationService: NSObject {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var tag = ""

    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    convenience init(tag: String) {
        self.init()
        self.tag = tag
    }

    func startUpdating() {
        print("tag:\(tag) startUpdating")
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func stopUpdating() {
        print("tag:\(tag) stopUpdating")
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func checkPermisson() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("notDetermined")
        case .restricted:
            print("restricted")
        case .denied:
            print("denied")
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("authorizedAlways")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("authorizedWhenInUse")
        }
    }
}

extension LocationService: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    //  このメソッドは locationManager.delegate = self を実行したタイミングでまず1回呼ばれる
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("tag:\(tag) didChangeAuthorization -> ", status.rawValue)
        if status == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            let latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
            let longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
            let timestamp = location.timestamp.description
            print("tag:\(tag) didUpdateLocations -> latitude:\(latitude) longitude:\(longitude) timestamp:\(timestamp)")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("tag:\(tag) didFailWithError -> ", error)
    }
}
```

自分として、以下のように書いてもいい気もしますが、

```
override init() {
        super.init()
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
```

様々な資料を読んでも全てプロパティにセットしてあります。
分かる方いましたら、ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

下の書き方では、`init`が終了した時に`locationManager`のインスタンスが解放され、`delegate`に`self`を保持した`locationManager`のインスタンスが無くなってしまうからです。

プロパティにすると言うことは、そのクラスのインスタンスが存在する間、プロパティが破棄されないことの保証になります。

しかし、インスタンスを`init`の中のローカル変数にしてしまうと、`init`が終了した際にローカル変数は破棄されますので、`locationManager`（特に`delegate`に自身を保持した）がどこにも無くなってしまうからです。

Comment: チャイカ様　ご回答ありがとうございます。　一つ質問なのですが、この場合のselfは、LocationServiceクラスのインスタンスではないでしょうか？　delegateで指定したselfは、CLLocationManager()のインスタンスであるlocationManagerでしょうか？

Comment: 追記になりますが、delegateで指定したselfは、LocationServiceクラスのインスタンスの中にあるCLLocationManager()のインスタンスであるlocationManagerでしょうか？

Comment: いいえ、`NSObject`の子クラスである、`LocationService`クラスのインスタンスになります。

Comment: チャイカ様　ご回答ありがとうございます。

LocationService内のlocationManagerプロパティは、
locationManager型のプロパティではなく
locationManagerDelegate型を採用することは出来ませんか？
様々な資料を読んで、delegate元となるプロパティとして、Delegate型(プロトコル)を採用している方法も見つけました。
[参考](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/33867)
Delegate型(ここでは、locationManagerDelegate型)かdelegateプロパティを持っているクラスの型(ここでは、locationManager型)を定義する違いについて、是非ご教授して頂きたいです。

長々、質問させて頂いておりますがよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 参考で貼らしていた頂いたdelegate型のプロパティは、delegate処理を単純にdelegate先に登録するが、
今回のdelegateプロパティを持っているクラスの型を定義することは、クラスの中でさらにクラスを定義し、そのクラスのプロパティがdelegate型を持っているから、この方法で記述すると考えましたが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: class LocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate として、`LocationService`クラスが`CLLocationManagerDelegate`プロトコルに準拠するのが一般的です。そのための`locationManager.delegate = self`です。`extension`を除いて`self`は上方向に辿って一番近い `class`文のインスタンスを指します。まず、誤解がありそうなのは、`CLLocationManager`型のインスタンスは必ず保持する必要があると言うことです。そうしないと`CLLocationManager`クラスのメソッドが呼べません。その上で、`CLLocationManagerDelegate`に準拠したクラスを別に作り、そのインスタンスも保持することは出来ますが、では`LocationService`クラスは何のためにあるの？という話になりませんか？

Comment: これ以上は`Delegate`に対する理解の別質問となりそうなので、更に疑問がある場合は別に質問を立てて下さい

Comment: チャイカ様　ご回答ありがとうございます。理解が深まり、本当に感謝しております。
頂いた質問に対して、自分の考えを含めた新しく質問を立てさせて頂いたので、ぜひご教授頂きたいです。
[新しい質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/77964/delegate%e3%81%ae%e9%9a%9b%e3%81%ae-%e5%91%bc%e3%81%b3%e5%87%ba%e3%81%97%e5%85%83%e3%82%af%e3%83%a9%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ae%e6%84%8f%e5%91%b3%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af)

引き続きよろしくお願い致します。